# jQuery Ajax function not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm making a sort of voting system plugin for my website. When the user clicks the 'like' button, jQuery ajax is supposed to send that click to a function in my `functions.php` which i called `vote_funct`. The jQuery ajax script is returning a success message, but the function is simply not being called. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Below is my jQuery ajax code:

```
(function($){  //wordpress jquery no conflict starts here
 $(document).ready( function($) {
     var counter;
     var id;
     var ajaxurl = MyAjax.ajax_url;

     $('.fa-plus').click(function(){
        counter = 0;
        id      = $(this).closest('div').prop("id");
        counter = counter+1;
        $(this).css('color','green');
        $(this).removeClass('fa fa-plus');
        $(this).addClass('fa fa-check');        

        $.ajax({
            url    : ajaxurl,
            type   : "POST",
            data   : {
                        'action' : 'vote_funct',
                        'counter': counter,
                        'id'     : id
                        },
        success:function(data){
        console.log("counter");
    }
        }).error(function(xhr, status){
            switch(status){
                case 404:
                    alert("404 not found");
                    break;
                case 500:
                    alert("500 server error");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    alert("0 request aborted");
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("unknown " + ajaxurl);

            }
    });
}) ;     
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

Then my `vote_funct` which is located in functions.php

```
$myfile = fopen("data.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_POST));

 function vote_funct(){
              $id    = $_POST['id'];
              $votes = $_POST['counter'];

            if( !empty( $_POST ) ){
              global $wpdb;
               $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE fwwp_votes SET votes = votes +1 WHERE id = $id") ); 
            }
          echo true;
          die();
        }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_vote_funct', 'vote_funct' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_vote_funct', 'vote_funct' );
```

FYI `data.txt` is writing all the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of jQuery you are using the "error" function could be deprecated (removed since jQuery 3.0)..

If that's the case try changing this..

```
}).error(function(xhr, status){
```

to this (http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)..

```
}).fail(function(){
```